# What is the effect of the second argument to generate_subscripts?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to understand the second argument to the PostgreSQL `generate_subscripts` function. The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) states that the second argument is the dimension of the array over which subscripts should be generated:

> generate_subscripts is a convenience function that generates the set
>   of valid subscripts for the specified dimension of the given array.

However, for my two-dimensional example array, providing arguments `1` or `2` both generate the same output.

```
WITH data AS (
    select (array[['1','spam','3'], ['4','eggs','6'], ['7','ham','9']]) AS arr
)
SELECT arr[i][2] AS food
FROM data,
generate_subscripts((SELECT arr FROM data), 1) i;
```

and

```
WITH data AS (
    select (array[['1','spam','3'], ['4','eggs','6'], ['7','ham','9']]) AS arr
)
SELECT arr[i][2] AS food
FROM data,
generate_subscripts((SELECT arr FROM data), 2) i;
```

(Note `1` vs. `2`) both generate the same output:

```
 food
------
 spam
 eggs
 ham
(3 rows)
```

I'm afraid that I don't understand the second argument to `generate_subscripts`. Can someone with more experience clarify what this argument does?

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A second parameter is dimension:

```
postgres=# select * from generate_subscripts(array[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],1);
 generate_subscripts 
---------------------
                   1
                   2
(2 rows)

postgres=# select * from generate_subscripts(array[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],2);
 generate_subscripts 
---------------------
                   1
                   2
                   3
(3 rows)
```

In your example, both dimensions are same size, so generate_subscripts returns same result.

Comment: Ah, I get it now! Though I was confused because you used integers as your array members. I modified your example and used strings, which made it a lot more clear to me: `select * from generate_subscripts(array[['dog','cat','zebra'],['horse','tiger','banana']],2);`. Thank you!